# Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'convert' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

so i was trying to make a giveaway command by watching some tutorials from yt
and i got an error ....actually i defined **convert** in code but its shows error **Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'convert' is not defined**. but the tutorials i watched didnt had the error.....and also i m using discord.py rewrite........ Any Help Is Appriciated :).

Code:

```py
class Giveaway(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    def convert(time):
        pos = ["s", "m", "h", "d"]
        time_dict = {"s" : 1, "m" : 60, "h" : 3600, "d" : 3600*24}
        unit = time[-1]

        if unit not in pos:
            return -1
        try:
            val = int(time[:-1])
        except:
            return -2

        return val * time_dict[unit]

    @commands.command()
    async def giveaway(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Answer The Following Questions For Giveaway:")

        questions = ["Channel For Giveaway?",
                     "Duration Of Giveaway? (s , m , h , d)",
                     "Prize Of Giveaway?"]

        answers = []

        def check(m):
            return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

        for i in questions:
            await ctx.send(i)

            try:
                msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', timeout=20.0, check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send('You Did Not Answer In Time!')
                return
            else:
                answers.append(msg.content)

        try:
            c_id = int(answers[0][2:-1])
        except:
            await ctx.send(f'Mention Channel Properly! Example: {ctx.channel.mention}')
            return

        channel = self.client.get_channel(c_id)

        time = convert(answers[1])
        if time == -1:
            await ctx.send(f'Answer Time With A Proper Unit (s, m, h, d)')
            return
        elif time == -2:
            await ctx.send(f'Time Must Be A Integer!')
            return

        prize = answers[2]

        await ctx.send(f'Giveaway Will Be In Channel {channel.mention} And Will Last {time}.')

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaway", description=f"{prize}", color=ctx.author.color)
        embed.add_field(name="Hosted by:", value= ctx.author.mention)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Ends after {answers[1]} from now. ")

        g_msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)

        await g_msg.add_reaction("")

        await asyncio.sleep(time)

        new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(g_msg.id)

        users = await g_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(self.client.user))

        winner = random.choice(users)

        await channel.send(f'Congrats! {winner.mention} won {prize}!')
```

ERROR:

```
 time = convert(answers[1])
NameError: name 'convert' is not defined
```

and

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'convert' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be referencing that method as `self.convert`:

`time = self.convert(answers[1])`

In addition, the signature for the `convert` method should start with the `self` parameter:

`def convert(self, time):`

You should learn how [classes work in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)!

Comment: i knew that we have to use self in cogs but was new to defining and using them furthur in code ....this helped me ...thanks very much

Comment: if it solved your problem, accept it as the answer by clicking the checkmark on his answer

Comment: You don't need `self` as a parameter if decorated with `@staticmethod`, since the function doesn't reference `self`.  It could also be moved outside the class as a generic helper function and be called as is with `convert` instead of `self.convert`.